# Formatting on gdb examine memory

Tags: c++, gdb

When debugging a C/C++ code, I examine memory using the following command

```
(gdb)x/32xub data
0x7fef824b2c6a: 8   0   39  235 101 169 0   30
0x7fef824b2c72: 73  219 25  195 8   0   69  0
0x7fef824b2c7a: 0   60  17  223 64  0   54  6
0x7fef824b2c82: 245 43  85  190 0   3   147 32
```

I would like have 16 bytes in a row and each byte shows in 2 hex digits.
Not sure what to do. Don't see any help from [reference manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html).
Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE1**

Just realized that when doing it again, it shows every bytes in hexdigits. However, it's 8 bytes per row, not 16.

```
(gdb) x/32x prevPkt
0x7fef824b2c6a: 0x08    0x00    0x27    0xeb    0x65    0xa9    0x00    0x1e
0x7fef824b2c72: 0x49    0xdb    0x19    0xc3    0x08    0x00    0x45    0x00
0x7fef824b2c7a: 0x00    0x3c    0x11    0xdf    0x40    0x00    0x36    0x06
0x7fef824b2c82: 0xf5    0x2b    0x55    0xbe    0x00    0x03    0x93    0x20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a macro. (This is adapted from my answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813099/2554472)).

```
define xb16
    dont-repeat
    set $addr = (char *)($arg0)
    set $endaddr = $addr + $arg1
    while $addr < $endaddr
        printf "%p: ", $addr
        set $lineendaddr = $addr + 16
        if $lineendaddr > $endaddr
            set $lineendaddr = $endaddr
        end
        set $a = $addr
        while $a < $lineendaddr
            printf "0x%02x ", *(unsigned char *)$a
            set $a++
        end
        printf "\n"
        set $addr = $addr + 16
    end
end

document xb16
usage: xb16 address count
outputs bytes in hex, 16 per row
end
```